# Has anyone been able to use the new Experimental ably-js react hooks?

Tags: next.js, ably-realtime

Problem: I encounter a "Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Connection closed" every time I attempt to use useChannel or usePresence. This is being done in a client component (app router), and the component is the child of a layout with AblyProvider.

This is [the error I received](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdiTs.png).

I do know this is experimental, but I just wanted to make sure it isn't just me and the hooks are working just fine.

What I tried:

1. Passing a client ID to the AblyProvider
2. Passing a client ID to each instance of a useChannel or usePresence hook
3. Using the provider in a layout
4. Using the provider in a component that just wraps the client component I want to use the hooks in
5. Cry a lot

Answer (score 1):

So, I solved it myself. For those who come across this later:

It works if you create your own Ably client and pass it in to the provider.

```js
import { AblyProvider } from "ably/react";
import * as Ably from "ably";

const client = new Ably.Realtime.Promise({ key: "your-ably-api-key", clientId: 'me' });

root.render(
  <AblyProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </AblyProvider>
)
```

Comment: Hey Atridad, I'm glad to see you got this resolved, I'm a devrel engineer at Ably and I'm wondering whether you would add your original code so we can take a look at whether we need to update our docs. Thanks, Tom

Comment: @TomCamp Sure! So I never committed the code that broke, but this is what I have working now...
Layout with Provider: https://github.com/atridadl/Atash/blob/main/src/app/(client)/layout.tsx
Hook Usage: https://github.com/atridadl/Atash/blob/main/src/app/(client)/room/%5Bid%5D/VoteUI.tsx

Comment: But essentially, what didn't work was passing the "options" object to the provider. I ended up needing to make the client and pass that.

Comment: Thanks very much for sharing this, I'll pass it back to the team.